# Efficient way to query all records where a field is not null in objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want to query an indexed field efficiently to retrieve all records where the indexed field is not null (present in the index). The field to be queried contains a `Ref<T>` to another entity, in case this is relevant.

What I could do is an inequality search, like `.filter/.filterKey("fieldname >=", "a")`, where a is the smallest ASCII that I want to grab.

But is this efficient? Or can I do an equality search somehow, which returns all records that are present in the index?

--

This is how my data looks like: I want to filter all records where the "overlay" column has a key, and omit those where the field is not set. I would like to use an equality filter if possible, so I don't need a composite index (as I am filtering on other fields at the same time).

[image: snapshot of data]

--

I can use this to test for `!= null`

```
.filter("user >", "\uFFFD");
```

and this to test for `== null`

```
.filter("user <", "\uFFFD");
```

I guess that's not the way it should be done. Is there a way to solve this problem using equality instead of inequality?

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what you're trying to do? An example data model would help.

Comment: I have added a screenshot from the app engine console. I think this explains it best.

Comment: I have added more information about a possible query to test for null, but I guess that's not the way this should be done.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to query for entities which have a null value for an indexed field:

```
ofy().load().type(Thing.class).filter("fieldname !=", null)
```

However, this is not the same thing as an equality filter. Under the covers, GAE treats != as a pair of filters (> and <) and this brings with it the limitations of inequality filters.

If you need an equality filter on "not null", create a synthetic indexed field in your entity which is populated using an @OnSave method. You can use a partial index on the 'true' value to limit the cost of indexing this extra data (ie, `@Index(IfTrue.class)`)

Answer (score 0):

If your property is String, a more efficient way than "!= null" is to use:

```
ofy().load().type(Thing.class).filter("fieldname >=", "");
```

Similarly, you can use > 0 if your property is a positive number, etc.