# The best way to filter all Record where the key/ref is not null in Objectify 5

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

How can I query an indexed key/ref field to retrieve all record which is not null? ie.I have Customer entity which contain a ref/key field which is unBilledOrder_ key, I want to filter out those customer has unBilledOrder_ key.

I have tried these way but it did not work.
`.filter("unBilledOrder_ !=", null) or .filterKey("unBilledOrder_ !=", null).

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25834899/efficient-way-to-query-all-records-where-a-field-is-not-null-in-objectify

Comment: I found the solution, it is index sorting issue.. Just create a datastore-indexed XML will do, please ref https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/objectify-appengine/SsjM-OHihRc